# arithmetic expression evaluation from left to right or reverse?

Tags: c++

Here I got o/p as '1', but my expectation was '100'. Why is it so? Please shed some light. Thank you!

```
int main()
    {
            cout << 100 / 10 / 10 << endl;
    }
```

Comment: If you are not 100% sure, use parenthesis - because other readers of the code may have the same "question" when looking over the code.

Comment: It's not really about "evaluation order" but rather "associativity" (which gives the order of evaluation of the operations, as opposed to their operands).

Answer (score 5):

Evaluation is done left to right for arithmetic operators having same precedence. That's why you are getting 1 -

1. First, 100 is divided by 10, resulting 10
2. the result is again divided by 10, resulting 1

Check out this [Precedence Table](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).

Answer (score 0):

When operators have the same priority, they are evaluated from left to right.

This is basic algebra.

Comment: Not sure about "basic algebra"... Consider the hypothetical exponentiation operator `**`: `a**b**c` should rather be `a**(b**c)` i.e. right-associative.

Answer (score 0):

From page 257 of TCPPL 4th Edition

> Unary operators and assignment operators are right-associative; all
>   others are left-associative. For example, a=b=c means a=(b=c) whereas
>   a+b+c means (a+b)+c